# Let $T \ : \ V\rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation such that $T^2=I$, that is, $T\circ T=I \implies T(T(v))=v$. Show T is an isomorphism.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For the case of $V$ being finite-dimensional, let dim$(V)=n$. Let $v\in V$ and $T(v)=0$.
\begin{align*}
    T(0)&=v \\
    T(T(0))&=T(v)\\
    T(T(0))&=0 \\
    \implies v&=0 \\
\end{align*}
So ker$(T)=\{0\}$, which implies that $T$ is one-to-one. \
Since we are assuming dim$(V)=n$, we know by rank-nullity that
\begin{align*}
    dim(V)&=dim(ker(T))+dim(ran(T)) \\
    n &= 0+dim(ran(T)) \\
    n &= dim(ran(T))
\end{align*}
So $T$ is onto and a linear isomorphism in the case of a finite-dimensional vector space.

For the infinite-dimensional case, let $V$ be infinite-dimensional and $V_n$ be $n$-dimensional. Let $v\in V$. Then $v\in V_n$ for some $n$. Since $T(v)=0\implies v=0$ for $v\in V_n$, $T(v)=0\implies v=0$ for $v\in V$ since any $v\in V$ is also in $V_n$. So ker$(T)=\{0\}$ and $\iota$ is one-to-one over $V$. Let $w\in V$, then $w\in V_n$ for some $n$ and we know $\exists v\in V_n$ such that $T(v)=w$ since $T$ is onto over $V_n$. So we know for any $w\in V$, $\exists v\in V$ such that $T(v)=w$ and we have that $T$ is onto over $V$ since any $w\in V$ is also in $V_n$. So $T$ is a linear isomorphism over an infinite-dimensional vector space. $\square$

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. I'm not so sure about your argument in the infinite-dimensional case. It sounds like you've proved "if $V$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space and $T: V \to V$ has $T^2 = I$, then whenever $v \in V$ and $W$ is a finite-dimensional subspace containing $v$, there's some $w \in W$ with $T(w) = v$". But this is false. Is your definition of isomorphism "bijective linear map"? If so then Mark's answer may not be the intended solution. You can see it's always surjective by using $T(T(v)) = v$. Do you see how? (Don't overthink it!)

Answer (score 8):

It's much easier than that. In order to be an isomorphism, $T$ needs to have an inverse linear map $S:V\to V$. But the assumption $T^2=I$ simply means that $T$ is an inverse of itself, so in particular an inverse exists.

No need to use anything nontrivial, like the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: So this applies to both finite and infinite dimensional cases? So I can say, $T$ is invertible because $T(T(v))=v \implies T(v)=T^{-1}(v)$ and thus $T$ is an isomorphism. Is this really a one-liner?

Comment: @JohnAllen I wouldn't write it like that, because we can't use the notation $T^{-1}(v)$ before we know $T^{-1}$ exists. I would write: $T\circ T=I$ means by definition that $T$ is an inverse of itself, and so $T$ is invertible. And yes, it works in all cases.